# Why does the image histogram with ASCII text embedded look this way?

Tags: steganography

[image]

[image]

I used histogram attack on image with embedded text ASCII(LSB-method) and found the chi square value. All observed frequencies more than expected frequencies, that is tipical for empty image, and have almost the same difference. Also the p-value is too big, though the data is embedded. Why do we observe this phenomenon?

Comment: Surely the frequencies can't *all* be higher, unless the image got bigger?

Comment: no, embedded image has the same size as empty